# VS Express 2013 RC for Web - system cannot find the file specified error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've just downloaded, and installed VS Express RC 2013 on my W7 laptop.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads#d-2013-express

I clicked Create New Project, and accepted all the defaults:
[image: New Project]
[image: Application Defaults]
However, immediately following pressing the Create Project button above, I get this message:
`The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)`
[image: Error message]

I've rebooted the laptop etc - but still get this message - but it's not giving me anything to go on, and I can't find a similar problem posted on SO/Google etc.

Can anyone shed any light on this, or suggest a fix for it?

**Update:** I tried this fix for 2012 edition, but the error still occurred: http://forums.asp.net/t/1887489.aspx

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: What happens if you target .NET 4.5.1 at the same time?

Comment: Hi - exact same I'm afraid - whether 4.5 or 4.5.1 - I also tried "repairing" and restarting, but again, no luck - thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this resolved it - but I can now load a project without the error message.  I went to package manager, and installed NuGet2.7 - Mark

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem. Installing NuGet 2.7 fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same error on VS2013.

Run the NuGet.Tools.vsix.exe file under C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Visual Studio 12
Start vs2013 again and you should be able to create the mvc project.

Comment: Glad I found your comment! :) Don't know why VS2013 Pro didn't do this during the install :s

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2013 Premium, and installing NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013 from Extensions and Updates resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes installing Nuget did work for me however I did have 2 different nuget exe's sitting under VS 2013 and 2012.

None of those worked for me as they were not installing due to "Already installed" message.

What worked for me (VS 2013) was to downloaded the latest Nuget from codeplex which successfully installed and solved the issue.

This is the direct download link that fixed my issue: https://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/879740

Answer (score 0):

Simply Uninstall the Nuget package from

Tools-->Extentions and updates-->(Search Nuget) then Uninstall this Nuget version

and Restart the visual studio.

After that need to add nuget package like this procedure and restart the visual studio.

Now it works....